# No outgoing traffic allowed by Red Hat 8

Tags: linux, iptables, redhat

I have recently been given access to a VPS with Red Hat 8 installed. I need to enable outgoing traffic in order to install certain things, but currently this doesn't work. Here are some commands that I have tried:

```
# ping google.com
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2029ms
```

```
# traceroute --tcp google.com
traceroute to google.com (172.217.167.110), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
```

```
# iptables -L
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I have omitted the `INPUT` chain because it has potentially identifiable rules.

If I add a new rule that accepts everything, it doesn't help:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p all -j ACCEPT
```

```
# iptables -L
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

```
# nft list ruleset
table ip6 filter {
        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
                ip6 saddr fe80::/10 ip6 daddr fe80::/10  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto icmp  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto ipv6-icmp  counter packets 4 bytes 388 accept
                iifname "lo"  counter packets 64 bytes 3178 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip6 saddr 2001:388:608c:8a6:250:56ff:feba:6e26  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip6 saddr 2001:388:608c:8a6:250:56ff:feba:1c7b  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip6 saddr 2001:388:608c:8a6:250:56ff:feba:7d6f  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname != "lo" ip6 daddr ::1  counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
                 ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip6 saddr 2001:388:608c:4c80::/60 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip6 saddr 2001:388:608c::/48 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip6 saddr fdfd:eb1a:eb10::/44 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip6 saddr fe80::/10 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip6 saddr 2001:388:608c:8d0:250:56ff:feb5:3aee tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip6 saddr 2001:388:608c:8d0:16fe:b5ff:fe91:3685 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip6 saddr 2001:388:608c:8d0:250:56ff:feb5:4296 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip6 saddr 2001:388:608c:8d0:250:56ff:feb5:22f7 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        }

        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        }
}
table ip raw {
        chain PREROUTING {
                type filter hook prerouting priority raw; policy accept;
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type filter hook output priority raw; policy accept;
        }
}
table ip mangle {
        chain PREROUTING {
                type filter hook prerouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        }

        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority mangle; policy accept;
        }

        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority mangle; policy accept;
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type route hook output priority mangle; policy accept;
        }

        chain POSTROUTING {
                type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        }
}
table ip nat {
        chain PREROUTING {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        }

        chain INPUT {
                type nat hook input priority 100; policy accept;
        }

        chain POSTROUTING {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
        }
}
table ip filter {
        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
                meta l4proto icmp  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "lo"  counter packets 2 bytes 100 accept
                iifname != "lo" ip daddr 127.0.0.0/8  counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.12.225  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.12.229  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 10.21.7.22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.12.242  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                 ct state related,established counter packets 131542 bytes 31134584 accept
                ip saddr 172.16.5.192/26  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.20.70 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.20.71 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.20.72 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.20.73 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 10.0.0.0/8 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.0.0/16 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 169.254.0.0/16 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 172.16.0.0/20 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 49.127.0.0/17 tcp dport 22  counter packets 1 bytes 60 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.19.9 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.19.14 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.19.15 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.19.82 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.19.83 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.19.7 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.19.28 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 130.194.19.45 tcp dport 22  counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        }

        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        }
}
```

Are there any other commands I might try to diagnose this issue? Does the information I have attached provide any insight into why outgoing traffic is all dropping?

Comment: There's no indication in your post that shows it must be the output traffics being dropped.

Comment: There is the line `ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` within the `INPUT` chain, so I think that should ensure that all responses are received.

Comment: Always check with `iptables-save`. (Or `-S` of `iptables`.) Also note that rule order matters.

Comment: The same rules appear if I use `iptables-save`.

Comment: Have you consider the fact that it might not even have anything to do with the firewall? (But e.g. routes or even VPS admin settings?) And no one but you can tell how exactly your firewall is configured without a full dump. (Btw, you may also check `nft list ruleset` just in case.)

Comment: I've added the output from that command to the original post. I am aware there could be other possible causes, but I don't know how to diagnose those causes, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well from the nft counters I'm not seeing anything being dropped. Is the VPS in some country that bans Google? Have you tried to reach any other sites? Maybe you should just seek help from the VPS provider.